# Maximum possible measure and dimension in SAP UI5 Viz Chart (Line, Stacked Bar, etc.)?

Tags: graph, charts, sapui5, dimension, measure

Working with SAP UI5 Viz chart (Line, Bar, Stacked-bar, pie, waterfall etc.). I am trying to make Line chart with 4 measure with 2 dimension and Stacked-bar with 5 measure with one dimension. But in Line can see only two lines (but 4 measure title is showing) and three stacked-bar where I need 2 more. In UI5 is there any limit for these or can I work with 'N' number of measure and dimension?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I resolved it, its unlimited. I can able to generate 7 measures in a report

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved it, its unlimited. I can able to generate 7 measures in a report. My mistake was column assigning.